# Running is fine but rename() does not work

Tags: c

Simple function code to delete a line from a text file by making a temporary text file that will store the new content once the line has been deleted and replacing the old **Storage.txt** file with the temporary file.

The `delete()` function works but my only problem seems to be the `rename()` function that seemingly won't do as intended.

**THE CODE**

```
void delete() {
    struct task task;
    FILE *fp;
    char str[100];
    char ch;
    int delete_line = 0;
    fp = fopen("Storage.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file");
        fopen("Storage.txt", "w");
        exit (1);
    }
    printf("\n\n\nAll Tasks\n");
    printf("----------\n\n");
    do {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        printf("%c", ch);
    } while (ch != EOF);
    fclose(fp);
    int line_no,ret;
    char filename[] = "Storage.txt";
    char newname[] = "temp.txt";
    FILE *file, *temp;
    file = fopen("Storage.txt", "r");
    temp = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    printf("Select Line to delete: ");
    scanf("d", &delete_line);
    getchar();
    temp = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    while (fgets(str, 99, fp) != NULL) {
        line_no++;
        if (line_no != delete_line) {
            fputs(str, temp);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    fclose(temp);
    remove(filename);
    ret = rename(newname, filename);
    if (ret == 0) {
        printf("File renamed successfully");
    } else {
        printf("Error: unable to rename the file");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"seemingly won't do as intended"* Wat does it do?

Comment: It runs smoothly. It's just that the rename() function wont do anything and from the if condition it prints back "Error: unable to rename the file".

Comment: `rename(newname, filename);` : `newname` is suspicious. Either the naming of your variables is terrible or you misread the documentation. But apparently there are more bugs elsewhere, look at the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in the code:

- `ch` must be defined with type `int` to detect `EOF` reliably.
- the `do`/`while` loop to read the file contents outputs the `EOF` indicator before testing it. You should use `while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) putchar(ch);`
- the identifier `delete` should be avoided to avoid confusing C++ programmers, use `delete_line` instead.
- you should test for failure of `fopen` and `remove` and display the cause of the error.
- if opening the file for reading fails, why do you create the file with `fopen("Storage.txt", "w")` ?
- file **temp.txt** is open twice, which may prevent the rename operation on legacy systems.
- `line_no` is not initialized. It should be initialized to `1` if lines are numbered starting at `1`.
- reading lines into an array is not reliable for this task as lines longer than 99 bytes will be counted more than once.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void delete_line() {
    const char *filename = "Storage.txt";
    const char *tempname = "temp.txt";
    int ch;

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\n\n\nAll Tasks\n");
    printf("----------\n\n");
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)  {
        putchar(ch);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    int delete_line = 0;
    printf("Select Line to delete: ");
    if (scanf("d", &delete_line) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing input\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // read and discard the rest of the user input line
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE *temp = fopen(tempname, "w");
    if (temp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n", tempname, strerror(errno));
        fclose(file);
        exit(1);
    }
    int line_no = 1;
    while ((ch = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (line_no != delete_line)
            putc(ch, temp);
        if (ch == '\n')
            line_no++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    fclose(temp);

    if (remove(filename)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot remove %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
    } else {
        if (rename(tempname, filename)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot rename %s as %s: %s\n",
                    tempname, filename, strerror(errno));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have fully edited my program and it now works as intended thank you kindly for your input @chqrlie!!!!!

Comment: @bryanLee: you can accept this or another answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

Your code opens the "temp.txt" file twice:

```
temp = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
...
temp = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
```

And closes it once. That will leave one open file descriptor to the file, untill the program exits.

`remove()` uses `unlink()` for deleting files. The man page of `unlink()` says:

> If the name was the last link to a file but any processes still have
> the file open the file will remain in existence until the last file
> descriptor referring to it is closed.

Ensure that all file descriptors are closed when not needed anymore.

The `rename` may fail, if file of `oldpath` or `newpath` is still open.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @SKi I have fully resolved the issue and is now working thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The two main bugs here are:

1.
`scanf("d", ...)` instead of
`scanf("%d", ...)`

`scanf()` needs a format string to know how to parse the input, just like `printf()` (the f is for format) needs it to know how to construct the output; and their format string syntax is almost the same.

2.
Unintialized `line_no`, meaning that it's not guaranteed to start at 0/1, thus it might not ever be equal to `delete_line`, and will not delete the line.

Comment: I have reviewed the bugs and removed them and is now fully working as intended thank you so much for your input! @malkaroee

Answer (score 0):

temp = fopen("temp.txt", "w");  Call it twice